# Get element from Gmail DOM with Chrome Extensions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to get an element from the DOM of Gmail. The element has a class named "**.yP**" (which is the element that shows the name of people who are involved in an email in the inbox list).

In the manifest field I have this entry:

```
    "content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": [
            "https://mail.google.com/*", 
            "https://inbox.google.com/*"
        ],
        "css": ["styles/test.css"],
        "js": [
            "libraries/jquery-3.4.1.min.js",
            "content-scripts/test.js"
        ],
        "run_at": "document_end"
    }
]
```

The content of the CSS file is that one:

```
.yP:hover {
   background-color: yellow;
}
```

It is working perfectly, when I pass the mouse over the element the background turns yellow.

But, the problem is when I try to get these elements in my content-script test.js. The list is always null. However, if I do the same instruction in the dev console it works perfectly.

```
var list = document.getElementsByClassName("yP");
console.log("List: " + list);
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your javascript is likely being called prior to the page being loaded with the class you're looking for.

Have you tried wrapping it in a window on `load` listener?

```js
window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
  var list = document.getElementsByClassName("yP");
  console.log("List: " + list);
});
```

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event

Comment: No, I haven't and now it's working! Thank you very much